# inserting parameters from select into procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've got this select :

```
 SELECT  gp.name, gda.value
          FROM   game_definition_aff gda,
         GAME_PARAMETAR gp,
         game_aff ga,
         game_name gn    
         WHERE   4355 = ga.aff_id 
          AND   ga.id = gda.game_aff_id
          AND   gp.id = gda.game_parametar_id
          AND   15 = ga.game_name_id
          AND   gn.game_name_id = ga.game_name_id
          and gp.name in ( 'MIN_BET','MAX_BET','MAX_WIN')
```

which returns :

```
NAME       -      VALUE

MAX_WIN    -      100

MAX_BET    -       50

MIN_BET    -       10
```

And i've got procedure :

```
get_percentage (i_player_id, o_session_id, royal_tri_win, o_percentage,
                             o_min_bet,
                             o_max_bet,
                             o_max_win,
                             o_pot
                            );
```

Now I need to insert values from select max_win,max_bet and min_bet into procedures parameters o_max_win,o_max_bet and o_bet_bet..

How can I do that ?

PS. this is procedure where is this code from above. and where are defined all parameters that is used in it..

```
   PROCEDURE open_session_3w (
      i_player_id              NUMBER,
      old_session_id           NUMBER,
      i_ip_address             VARCHAR2,
      i_machine_number         VARCHAR2,
      o_last_bet         OUT   NUMBER,
      o_min_bet          OUT   NUMBER,
      o_max_bet          OUT   NUMBER,
      o_max_win          OUT   NUMBER,
      o_credits          OUT   NUMBER,
      o_session_id       OUT   NUMBER,
      o_state            OUT   VARCHAR2
   )
   IS
      o_percentage       NUMBER;
      o_pot              NUMBER;                    
      pom                weak_cur;
      p_active_session   NUMBER;
      p_parent           number;
      v_max_win           number;
      v_min_bet           number;
      v_max_bet           number;
   BEGIN
     select parent_id into p_parent from casino_users where party_id = i_player_id;
      check_pl_sess_3w (i_player_id, old_session_id);
      o_session_id :=

     player.open_new_session (i_player_id, i_ip_address,i_machine_number,'GAME SESSION');

 select MAX( CASE WHEN gp.name = 'MAX_WIN' THEN VALUE END ),
           MAX( CASE WHEN gp.name = 'MAX_BET' THEN VALUE END ),
           MAX( CASE WHEN gp.name = 'MIN_BET' THEN VALUE END )
    INTO v_max_win,v_max_bet,v_min_bet
          FROM   game_definition_aff gda,
         GAME_PARAMETAR gp,
         game_aff ga,
         game_name gn    
         WHERE   i_player_id = ga.aff_id 
          AND   ga.id = gda.game_aff_id
          AND   gp.id = gda.game_parametar_id
          AND   15 = ga.game_name_id
          AND   gn.game_name_id = ga.game_name_id
          and gp.name in ( 'MIN_BET','MAX_BET','MAX_WIN') ;

      player.get_percentage (i_player_id,
                             o_session_id,
                             royal_tri_win,
                             o_percentage,
                             COALESCE(v_min_bet,o_min_bet),
                             COALESCE(v_max_bet,o_max_bet),
                             COALESCE(v_max_win,o_max_win),
                             o_pot
                            );
```

Comment: 3 rows, max win, max bet and min bet with their values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MAX(CASE WHEN) and store each value in 3 variables.

```
DECLARE
v_max_win NUMBER;
v_max_bet NUMBER;
v_min_bet NUMBER;
BEGIN

    select MAX( CASE WHEN gp.name = 'MAX_WIN' THEN VALUE END ),
           MAX( CASE WHEN gp.name = 'MAX_BET' THEN VALUE END ),
           MAX( CASE WHEN gp.name = 'MIN_BET' THEN VALUE END )
    INTO v_max_win,v_max_bet,v_min_bet
    FROM
    game_definition_aff gda,
             GAME_PARAMETAR gp,
             game_aff ga,
             game_name gn    
    ..

..

get_percentage (i_player_id, o_session_id, royal_tri_win, o_percentage,
                             COALESCE( v_min_bet,o_min_bet),
                             COALESCE( v_max_bet,o_min_bet),
                             COALESCE( v_min_win,o_max_win),
                             o_pot
                            );

END;
/
```

Alternatively if you want to avoid local variables, you may use implicit cursor loop.

```
for rec in ( --select query above )
LOOP
   get_percentage (i_player_id, o_session_id, royal_tri_win, o_percentage,
                             COALESCE( rec.min_bet,o_min_bet),
                             COALESCE( rec.max_bet,o_min_bet),
                             COALESCE( rec.min_win,o_max_win),
                             pot
                            );
END LOOP;
```

Comment: But what is the v_max_win,v_max_bet, v_min_bet are null then i will get no data . 
And I do this because if the these variables v_max_win,v_max_bet, v_min_bet are null then get_percentage should user o_min_bet,o_max_bet, o_max_win but if they are not null then I need to pass v_max_win,v_max_bet, v_min_bet  into get_percentage

Comment: @civesuas_sine : Please check I've added `COALESCE `

Comment: [Error] PLS-00363 (1091: 30): PLS-00363: expression '<expression>' cannot be used as an assignment target  * 3 times.. I need to declare some parameters as out ???

Comment: These  o_min_bet,o_max_bet, o_max_win  are out parameters and  v_max_win,v_max_bet,v_min_bet are declared just as number.

Comment: @civesuas_sine : I can't tell u more unless I know what your procedure is doing and how you have defined them. This answer solves the original question and has got nothing to do anything with the error.It should work if you have defined variables correctly.

Comment: @civesuas_sine :You may try defining variables as `in out ` instead of `out`. But, again I can't be sure if that's how u want it.

Comment: @civesuas_sine : That was not part of your original question. If you think I have answered your question, accept it. If you are not sure how to go about for further changes, please ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, i will accept it no problem , but i will open new question for this problem..